# Pivot Assistance Required

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table like this . Table 1.

```
Customer    Product     Value   Quantity    Order Number


Dave    Product 1   15  1   154
Dave    Product 2   25  5   154
Dave    Product 3   45  4   15
Rob     Product 2   222 33  233
```

Now I want this , Table 2.

```
Customer    Product 1 Quantity  Product 1 Value     Price per item ( Value /Quantity) for Product 1     Product 2 Quantity  Product 2 Value     Price per item ( Value /Quantity) for Product 2     Product 3 Quantity  Product 3 Value     Price per item ( Value /Quantity) for Product 3 Order Number 

Dave    1   15  15  5   25  5   null    null    null    154

Dave    null    null    null    null    null    Null    4   45  11.25   15

Rob     null    null    null    33  222 6.727272727 null    null    null    233
```

I was thinking about some pivot but wasn't sure how to construct it . Also the number of products is not fixed and change in Table 1.

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: Do you want the headers to say the actual Product Name (car, etc) or do you want a generic product1?

Comment: Actual Product Names please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the result, I would advise applying both an *unpivot* and a *pivot* to the data.

The UNPIVOT will convert the column data from your table into rows. Once the data is unpivoted, then you can apply a pivot.

Since you are using SQL Server 2008+ you can use CROSS APPLY with the VALUES clause to unpivot.  Prior to 2008, you could use the UNPIVOT function.  The code to unpivot the data is:

```
select t.customer,
  replace(t.product, ' ', '')+'_'+c.col piv_col, 
  c.val,
  t.ordernumber
from table1 t
cross apply
(
  values
    ('value', cast(value as varchar(10))),
    ('quantity', cast(quantity as varchar(10))),
    ('PricePerUnit', cast((value/quantity) *1.0 as varchar(10)))
) c (col, val);
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94e30/15). This converts the data into the following format:

```
| CUSTOMER |               PIV_COL |  VAL | ORDERNUMBER |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     Dave |        Product1_value |   15 |         154 |
|     Dave |     Product1_quantity |    1 |         154 |
|     Dave | Product1_PricePerUnit | 15.0 |         154 |
|     Dave |        Product2_value |   25 |         154 |
```

You can see that the row for `Dave` order 154 has been turned into rows and I have created the new column names that will be used for the pivot (`piv_col`). This column has concatenated the Product Name to the from of the previous column headers (value, quantity).

Since the data is in a single row, you can easily apply the pivot function to the data. The final code will be:

```
select customer,
  Product1_quantity, Product1_value, Product1_PricePerUnit,
  Product2_quantity, Product2_value, Product2_PricePerUnit,
  Product3_quantity, Product3_value, Product3_PricePerUnit,
  orderNumber
from
(
  select t.customer,
    replace(t.product, ' ', '')+'_'+c.col piv_col, 
    c.val,
    t.ordernumber
  from table1 t
  cross apply
  (
    values
      ('value', cast(value as varchar(10))),
      ('quantity', cast(quantity as varchar(10))),
      ('PricePerUnit', cast((value/quantity) *1.0 as varchar(10)))
  ) c (col, val)
) d
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for piv_col in(Product1_quantity, Product1_value, Product1_PricePerUnit,
                 Product2_quantity, Product2_value, Product2_PricePerUnit,
                 Product3_quantity, Product3_value, Product3_PricePerUnit)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94e30/16).

The above works great if you have a known number of products, but if not, then you will need to use dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(replace(t.product, ' ', '')+'_'+c.col) 
                    from Table1 t
                    cross apply
                    (
                      values ('value', 1), ('quantity', 0),('PricePerUnit', 3)
                    ) c (col, so)    
                    group by product, col, so
                    order by product, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT customer, ' + @cols + ', ordernumber
              from
              (
                select t.customer,
                  replace(t.product, '' '', '''')+''_''+c.col piv_col, 
                  c.val,
                  t.ordernumber
                from table1 t
                cross apply
                (
                  values
                    (''value'', cast(value as varchar(10))),
                    (''quantity'', cast(quantity as varchar(10))),
                    (''PricePerUnit'', cast((value/quantity) *1.0 as varchar(10)))
                ) c (col, val)
              ) d
              pivot
              (
                max(val)
                for piv_col in (' + @cols + ')
              ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c36b5/8).  These queries give the result:

```
| CUSTOMER | PRODUCT1_QUANTITY | PRODUCT1_VALUE | PRODUCT1_PRICEPERUNIT | PRODUCT2_QUANTITY | PRODUCT2_VALUE | PRODUCT2_PRICEPERUNIT | PRODUCT3_QUANTITY | PRODUCT3_VALUE | PRODUCT3_PRICEPERUNIT | ORDERNUMBER |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Dave |            (null) |         (null) |                (null) |            (null) |         (null) |                (null) |                 4 |             45 |                  11.0 |          15 |
|     Dave |                 1 |             15 |                  15.0 |                 5 |             25 |                   5.0 |            (null) |         (null) |                (null) |         154 |
|      Rob |            (null) |         (null) |                (null) |                33 |            222 |                   6.0 |            (null) |         (null) |                (null) |         233 |
```

Comment: +1 I only wish I could vote up more than once.Great answer..!!